# Node JS Script not recognizing proxies: ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES

Tags: node.js, proxy, node-modules

I have the following code to analyze the loading time of a group of URLs using proxies:

```
// Node JS script to analyze the loading time of group of URLs with proxies
// node loading-analyzer.js -u urls.txt -p proxies.txt
// npm install puppeteer yargs fs

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const yargs = require('yargs/yargs');
const { hideBin } = require('yargs/helpers');

const argv = yargs(hideBin(process.argv)).argv;

async function loadUrlWithProxy(url, proxy) {
    const proxyParts = proxy.split(':');
    const formattedProxy = `http://${proxyParts[2]}:${proxyParts[3]}@${proxyParts[0]}:${proxyParts[1]}`;
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: "new",
        args: [
            `--proxy-server=${formattedProxy}`,
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
        ]
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();

    await client.send('Network.enable');
    await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCookies');
    await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCache');

    await client.send('Performance.enable');

    const start = performance.now();
    await page.goto(url);
    const end = performance.now();

    const metrics = await client.send('Performance.getMetrics');
    const { metrics: { duration, loading, scripting, painting, rendering, other } } = metrics;

    console.log(`URL: ${url}`);
    console.log(`Total load time: ${end - start}`);
    console.log(`Resource Scheduling - Queueing: ${other}`);
    console.log(`Connection Start - Stalled: ${loading}`);
    console.log(`Connection Start - Proxy negotiation: ${scripting}`);
    console.log(`Connection Start - Initial connection: ${painting}`);
    console.log(`Connection Start - SSL: ${rendering}`);
    console.log(`Request/Response - Request sent: ${loading}`);
    console.log(`Request/Response - Waiting for server response: ${scripting}`);
    console.log(`Request/Response - Content Download: ${painting}`);

    await browser.close();
}

async function main() {
    const urlsFile = argv.u;
    const proxiesFile = argv.p;

    const urls = fs.readFileSync(urlsFile, 'utf-8').split('\n').filter(Boolean);
    const proxies = fs.readFileSync(proxiesFile, 'utf-8').split('\n').filter(Boolean);

    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        await loadUrlWithProxy(urls[i], proxies[i]);
    }
}

main();
```

However, I am getting the following error:

**Error: net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES**

My proxies are formatted this way: hostname:port:username:password

Is there something I am doing wrong?

The proxies are working because I have checked them with another tool. The proxies accept both http and https protocol. None of them are working with my script.

I believe it's a problem with Puppeteer and Proxies.